# SharePoint - Word Properties - only original from saved list template visible, but do not new or updated properties

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, word

We are runnning SharePoint 2016

Setup:

1. Create Document library and add required fields (at least one text field, so in word the property must be filled, and one choice field with a few choiced)
2. Save library as list template
3. Create new library from the saved template
4. Add a new required text field
5. Change the required choice field (add, remove and modify some choices)

Now comes the bug:

1. Open a word file (new or any which was not saved in sharepoint before)
2. In Word, save as --> Browse --> then copy the link of the new SharePoint library (from step 3 from before) in the address line and try to save the document to the newly created library

[image]

3. Now in Word a window opens on the right with the SharePoint library properties, but the properties are the one from the original library and the document can not be saved.

[image]

4. Strangely in the Info Panel, the correct properties are displayed and can be changed:

[image]

If propertities in the original library are changed, it is visible in the word propertites. So the properties in word access the original library and not from the newly created library I wanna save the word file to.

The funny stuff is, if you delete the original list, everything works fine and word displays the properties from the new list. So there has to be some connection.
Also if you create an empty word file directly from the new button in the browser, everything works too, even if the original is not deleted.

Does anyone have an idea, how to fix it? I can not delete the original outside this test.

Answer (score 0):

I got a response for a workaround for creating a new library template, so new libraries are working (see also comments below answer).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/663113/sharepoint-word-properties-only-original-from-save.html

But for now there is no solution for existing libraries for this problem.